# TypeScript does not show all of the Error constructors

Tags: javascript, typescript

My problem is quite simple:  I want to use the `Error` constructor that takes a message and an options object.  Even though my `tsconfig.json` file states that `"target": "es2020"`, VS Code's Intellisense only shows one constructor for `Error` (the one that only takes a message).  Furthermore, when I navigate to the definition, the file that shows up is called `lib.es5.d.ts`.

If I try to compile, I get the following message:

```
src/FetchedConfigDataSource.ts:46:37 - error TS2554: Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.

46                 throw new Error('', { cause: err });
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?  Let me know if I should elaborate on anything.

Comment: Did you close and reopen vscode after updating your tsconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think error cause wasn't implemented in 2020, I think you need to upgrade to ESNext or similar.

It's still a draft in the 2021 update:
https://tc39.es/proposal-error-cause/

[This](https://dev.to/brayanarrieta/new-javascript-features-ecmascript-2022-with-examples-4nhg) claims it was introduced in es2022.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct.  I don't know why I was so fixated with the idea it was in ES2020.  For people reading this issue, change your target to ES2022 and then restart VS Code for the Intellisense to pick up on your preference.

Comment: Note that ES2022 is already released and finalized.  The current draft is ES2023.

Answer (score 2):

The `options` parameter for [the `Error` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error) is not present in ES2020.  It was [introduced in ES2022](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2022/#sec-error-message) (you can see that it is [absent from ES2021](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2021/#sec-error-message)).  Therefore TypeScript has added this to its [typings for ES2022](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es2022.error.d.ts), and if you want this, you will need to use `"es2022"` or newer for your `--target`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4CwTg9g7gBAdgU1gUTJMAKA5FgNDAbxgGMBDAVwGcEAuGAInpgF8BKIA)